# Total progress for multiple async uploads via BlobClient.UploadAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, azure-blob-storage, progress-bar

I tested and found that for uploading a folder full of files to an Azure Blob Storage container, the fastest method (with the v12 Azure Storage SDK) involves using a Queue (`Queue<Task<Response<BlobContentInfo>>>`) and firing off an `UploadAsync()` for each file, ending in a `Task.WhenAll()`. The blob client coordinates max concurrency, etc. as configured. However, I need to show ***total* progress** across all files, and when I use the same `ProgressHandler` for each blob client, the `Progress<long>()` event only returns total bytes uploaded *per file*, without any context for the underlying file whose progress is being reported. How can I get the cumulative progress of multiple async uploads?

```html
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

public async Task UploadBlobs(string sourcePath)
{
  var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
  var tasks = new Queue<Task<Response<BlobContentInfo>>>();
  var progressHandler = new Progress<long>();
  progressHandler.ProgressChanged += UploadProgressChanged;

  var options = new BlobUploadOptions()
  {
      ProgressHandler = progressHandler,
      TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions()
      {
          MaximumConcurrency = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2,
          MaximumTransferSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024
      }
  };

  foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
  {
      string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
      Console.WriteLine($"Uploading {fileName}\r\n");
      var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

      tasks.Enqueue(blobClient.UploadAsync(filePath, options));
  }

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private void UploadProgressChanged(object sender, long bytesUploaded)
{
    // This handles every progress change for every file, but with no file context info!
}
```

Comment: Do you want to track the upload progress of each file or total upload progress of all files?

Comment: As stated in bold, I need the total progress of all files. I have the sum of the file sizes in the folder already for updating a progress bar (not shown), I just need to be able to identify each file in progress to track it (and the total).

Comment: For total progress, can't you create a global variable which you can update in `UploadProgressChanged` to indicate how many bytes in total are successfully uploaded. Let me check on individual file progress.

Comment: No. There are arbitrary progress updates that just provide the total number of bytes uploaded *so far*, which increases with each successive update - it's not an incremental value of "bytes since the last progress report". There's not a fixed number of updates per file (there may be none if the upload is tiny, I believe), and as stated above, if multiple blob clients are using a common handler, there's not an easy way to get info on which file is being reported on (that I'm aware of).

Comment: Can you check my answer below? It is using a different progress handler for each blob separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to track individual blob's upload progress is to create your own progress handler and pass `BlobClient` to it.

Here's a rudimentary implementation of this:

```
public class BlobUploadProgressChange : Progress<long>
{
    private readonly BlobClient _blobClient;

    public BlobUploadProgressChange(BlobClient blobClient) : base()
    {
        _blobClient = blobClient;
    }

    public BlobClient BlobClient
    {
        get { return _blobClient; }
    }
}
```

This is how you would modify the `UploadProgressChanged` event handler:

```
void UploadProgressChanged(object? sender, long bytesUploaded)
{
    BlobUploadProgressChange item = (BlobUploadProgressChange) sender;
    Console.WriteLine(item.BlobClient.Name);
    Console.WriteLine($"Bytes uploaded: {bytesUploaded}");
    Console.WriteLine("====================================");
}
```

and this is how you can use it:

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    Console.WriteLine($"Uploading {fileName}\r\n");
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
    var progressHandler = new BlobUploadProgressChange(blobClient);
    progressHandler.ProgressChanged += UploadProgressChanged;
    var options = new BlobUploadOptions()
    {
        ProgressHandler = progressHandler
    };
    tasks.Enqueue(blobClient.UploadAsync(filePath, options));
}
```

Comment: rather than writing to the consolse, how would send the progress to the front end?